Is it possible to integrate Safe to our DAO for Governance and Voting Functionality?
We are considering integrating Safe for governance and voting within our DAO.
Specifically, we’d like clarification on the following points:

Integration Solutions: What solutions should we use for governance
and voting with Safe, and how do we effectively integrate them into
our existing infrastructure?

Customization Options: Can we customize or white label the Safe
interface to align with our branding (logo, colors, etc.), and what
are the available options for doing this?

Integration Process: What does the integration process entail for
connecting Safe's governance and voting features with our
infrastructure?

Fees and Pricing: Are there any fees associated with using Safe's
services, particularly for integration? If so, what should we expect
in terms of costs?

Voting Rules: What customizable voting mechanisms does Safe offer
(e.g., thresholds, majority requirements, quorum, etc.), and how do we implement
them?

Onchain vs. Offchain: Does Safe support both onchain and offchain
governance and voting features?


Thanks in advance

Yeah sure, it is possible

You can integrate SafeSnap Snapshot for off-chain voting and on-chain execution
Yeah, and you can customize it to your taste since the safe frontend code is open-source. They also have SDKs that you can use to create your own custom design
Depending on how your infrastructure works, you mostly go through similar steps

Setting up your own Safe multi-sig wallet for treasury management
Implementing a SafeSnap or other Modules for governance and voting.
You can now do integration, testing and auditing to be sure everything works fine.


It's actually free, since its opensource.
You can define a couple of things like - How many votes are needed to pass a proposal , Voting power based on holdings , Voting periods and Number of people expected to vote for a decision to be made
It support both on-chain and o

